# Column count on webkit browsers

Tags: wordpress, css, webkit, column-count

I'm using this css code to manage columns in my page (I'm on wordpress 4.2.2 + Visual Composer Plugin):

```
  -webkit-columns: 2 200px;
 -moz-columns: 2 200px;
      columns: 2 200px;


-webkit-column-gap: 20px;
 -moz-column-gap: 20px;
      column-gap: 20px;
```

It works fine on Firefox but the whole paragraph disappears on Chrome and Safari (webkit).
Any suggestion?

EDIT: I can't add any screenshot (I need at least 10 reputation ti post images), so there's website  [link](http://www.memartlab.com)

Comment: I wouldn't use columns quite yet, mainly because they're not overly supported by many browsers.

Comment: Provide some screenshots - it may ease finding solution for people who read this.

Comment: Visual Composer allows you to create columns in Wordpress. Why would you have it hardcoded like this? 
Just give your columns (which you create with visual composer) an ID name   or  a Class name. And then using this ID or Class, tweak it the column in your text editor if you still need to tweak it.

Comment: Add working code snippet on http://jsfiddle.net please.